# How do i do a multiple selection of all ids of particular tag in sublime text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3, emmet

I have a html markup containing a relatively  big SVG file (48paths) .
How do i quickly select all ids withing path tags and be able to copy their content all in once ?

My second question if you'll allow it is: what is a quick shortcut to put each path tag inside an anchor tag  ?

Btw: i'm using sublime text 3 with emmet package already installed.

Comment: You can duplicate the curser by selection and pressing Ctrl+d.

Comment: That will select only the attribut "id" not its content ! Not convenient for me.